# LINQ to Entities select columns with expression parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I cannot wrap my head around how i manage to select columns in a queryable by specifying an expression as a parameter.

```
Method A(IQueryable<Order> query)
```

Inside Method A i want to specify which columns to select, so i dont get all columns right away, like this:

```
query.Select(x => new { x.OrderNumber, x.Payment, x.Customer })
```

This is easy if i specify this directly in Method A, but i want to pass the information using a parameter.
I tried using a expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<Order, dynamic>> columns
```

But i can't get it to work, since i can only specify one columns, where i call Method A, like this:

```
MethodA(query, (x) => x.OrderNumber);
```

How can i specify more than one property?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.
I simply had to specify an anonymous type like this:

```
MethodA(query, order => new { order.OrderNumber, order.Payment })
```

Now i can pass in my Select expression from other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass in column names, why not pass strings as an array?

`void MethodA(params string[] columns)`

Comment: I want to pass in properties using the LINQ way of doing things.
I basicly want to pass in the query.Select() expression.