# Get selected column from iqueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How can I return `fieldList` from an IQueryable object?

```
// fieldList="Code,Name";
var result = from Activity in query
select new 
{
  Code = Activity.Code,
  Name = Activity.Name,
  StatusCode = Activity.ClaimStatus.Name
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why don't you know the columns you want to select at compile time? How do you determine this `fieldlist`(get as parameter?)?

Comment: After creating the IQueryable object i want to return based on fieldList which is dynamic. I dont know at compilation time. Yes it will come as a parameter

Comment: You want to return an anonymous type from the method?

Comment: That will also be fine

Comment: No, it's not fine bacause you can't resolve this type on the other side.The whole requirement is unclear and can certainly be done in a better way.

Comment: So what is better way you think

Comment: You haven't told anything about what you are actually trying to avchieve and why you think you need this. So we can't show you a better way.

Comment: My requirement is simple fieldList is dynamic and i have IQueryable object available in system. example i have given you. Now i want to query based on fieldList

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241996/linq-to-entities-select-columns-with-expression-parameter

Comment: But there is no clear implementation available

Answer (score 0):

DTO

```
 public class CustomDto
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string StatusCode { get; set; }

        }
```

Convert To Dto

```
    var result = items.AsQueryable().Select(x => new CustomDto()
        {
            Code = x.Code,
            Name = x.Name,
            StatusCode = x.ClaimStatus
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: after creating the object i want to return column based on array fieldList it is dynamic

Comment: After creating the IQueryable object i want to return based on fieldList which is dynamic. I don't know at compilation time. It will come as a parameter

Comment: there is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516971/linq-dynamic-select